# adhoc builds for keyboard extensions

Tags: ios8

I am creating an adhoc build for a keyboard extension in ios 8. Somehow, the build fails to install in the iOS 8 iPhone when the build is shared via Testflight.

Is there a special way to prepare adhoc build for extensions or a different way of preparing them for Testflight? For example, is the bundle id for the target of the container app the same as the bundle id of the target for the extension?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you find the answer of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not any special way to create a adhoc build for iOS App extension just create your App adhoc build and its ready to upload on Testflight.

Bundle id should be different for App extension.

For example:

App bundle id: com.abc.myapp

Extension bundle id: com.abc.myapp.myextension

Comment: Is it necessary, then, to have a provisioning profile explicitly for the extension?

Comment: Yes you need a different App identifier and a provision profile for extension.

Comment: You should not be able to compile the app without a separate provisioning profile for the keyboard.